# Coffeescript - Use 'this' together function params

Tags: javascript, syntax, coffeescript

I'm beginner web programing, and I'm learning CoffeeScript from [documentaion](http://coffeescript.org/) , but I didn't understand fully. Now I have a question: if I have a `javascript` like this

```
bindCallback.apply(this, arguments);
```

how can I rewrite with `Coffeescript`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just remove the semicolon:

```
bindCallback.apply(this, arguments)
```

The parentheses can also be removed:

```
bindCallback.apply this, arguments
```

`this` is aliased to `@` as well:

```
bindCallback.apply @, arguments
```

Comment: is it work perfectly, i read about apply need to wrire like
`bindCallback arguments...` - with tree dot

Comment: The only way that you might have to use the three dots is if you were doing something like `func.call this, arguments...` - That would have the same result as above.